# Whatsapp Cloud API webhook not sending back the messages object

Tags: webhooks, whatsapp

One of my WA cloud Apps suddenly stopped working,
I went to the webhook and it is not sending the messages object back,
I am sure this happened suddenly

here is the result from webhook:

```
{
"object": "whatsapp_business_account",
"entry": [
    {
        "id": "1900820329959633",
        "changes": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
                    "metadata": {
                        "display_phone_number": "16315551234",
                        "phone_number_id": "16315551234"
                    },
                    "statuses": []
                },
                "field": "messages"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Meanwhile if you go to official WA [Postman collection](https://www.postman.com/meta/workspace/whatsapp-business-platform/request/13382743-b5e1cfac-45dc-41ec-8fed-ca8f3f140167) you will find that it already includes messages object.

Edit 1:

After some investigation I found that developer.facebook health check page has the following:

[image]

But still not sure if that's related.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Edit 2:

I tried another developer account that has cloud API, it works and sends back the messages Object correctly.

EDIT 3:

Now they are describing the same issue occurred.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information, we can't help you with just a not working statement. Show your implementation and debugging details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to report a bug to WA Team, and they were able to reproduce the error.